# How to use 2d array on ngmodel in angular 2?

Tags: html, angular, multidimensional-array, angular2-ngmodel

Would like to know how to set 2d array in ngmodel for dynamic checkbox?

I have a role and permission setup form for a super admin with multiple checkbox. 
[image]
How to differentiate model name with role id and permission id. I need to pass role id and permission id with the model name in an array.

eg : [(ngModel)]="permission[role.id][per.id]"

Is there a way to assign 2d value for ngmodel in Form?

Looking forward for an earliest response.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you already tried it?

Comment: yes, but its not working.

Answer (score 2):

As **ngModel** is directive to obtain 2-way binding system.

You can easily do the syntax:

```
[(ngModel)]="permission[role.id][per.id]"
```

where permission is an empty array defined initially as:

```
permission = []
```

or

```
permission = [[]]
```

where your **permission** variable will be a multidimensional array.

After this, if you try to ngModel

```
[(ngModel)]="permission[role.id][per.id]"
```

it will cause a **undefined** issue as ngModel not only gets the value from input it has to show also that is how are 2-way binding works.

To avoid issue while rendering due to undefined, we have to assign dummy data to the permission Array initially only.

```
this.permission = new Array(this.numberOfRoles).fill(0);
    for (let j = 0; j < this.numberOfRoles; j++) {
      this.permission[j] = new Array(this.numberOfPermission).fill(0);
    }
```

This solves the undefined issue such as below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N54xw.png)